# symmetric polynomials for Super Hecke Clifford algebra

Tags: hecke-algebras, clifford-algebras, super-algebra

Fix a natural number $n$. In https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1039, §3.5, Kang/Kashiwara/Tsuchioka define a (version of a) Hecke Clifford superalgebra. It is the superalgebra with the following generators:

- even generators $y_a$ for $1\leq a\leq n$
- even “crossings” $\sigma_a$ for $1\leq a<n$
- odd generators $\mathfrak c_a$ for $1\leq a\leq n$

I omit the generators $e(\nu)$ in the following. $\nu$ is a vector of length $n$ whose entries are either even or odd.

Among other relations (Def. 3.10 of that article), the crossing $\sigma$ and the even generator $y$ interact as follows:

$$\sigma_a y_{a+1}-y_a\sigma_a =
\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $\nu_a=\nu_{a+1}$ is even}\\
1-\mathfrak c_a\mathfrak c_{a+1} & \text{if $\nu_a=\nu_{a+1}$ is odd}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$\sigma_a y_{a}-y_{a+1}\sigma_a =
\begin{cases}-1 & \text{if $\nu_a=\nu_{a+1}$ is even}\\
-1-\mathfrak c_a\mathfrak c_{a+1} & \text{if $\nu_a=\nu_{a+1}$ is odd}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The for the odd generators, $\sigma_a\mathfrak c_a=c_{a+1}\sigma_a$, and similarly for $\mathfrak c_{a+1}$. The other $\mathfrak c$ and $y$ are unchanged by $\sigma$.

If we consider only the even case, then the divided differences

$$\begin{split}
\partial_a (x_a) &= -1\\
\partial_a(x_{a+1}) &= 1\\
\partial_a(x_j) &= 0~\text{for distant $j$}\\
\partial_a(fg) &= \partial_a(f)g + s_a(f)\partial_a(g)
\end{split}
$$
admit these relations.

**Question:** How to make the above defining relations for $\sigma$ into a divided difference operator, and what are its properties?

**Attempt:** Mimicking the even case, we can define 
$$\begin{split}
\tilde\partial_a (x_a) &= -1-\mathfrak c_ac_{a+1}\\
\tilde\partial_a(x_{a+1}) &= 1-\mathfrak c_ac_{a+1}\\
\tilde\partial_a(\mathfrak c_j) &= 0~\text{for all $j$}\\
\tilde\partial_a(x_j) &= 0~\text{for distant $j$}\\
\tilde\partial_a(fg) &= \tilde\partial_a(f)g + s_a(f)\tilde\partial_a(g)
\end{split}$$

Is this the only suitable definition for $\tilde\partial_a$? Is even a “useful“ operator? For instance, in the even case,
$\ker\partial_a=\operatorname{im}\partial_a$, and their intersection for all $a$ are precisely the symmetric polynomials in the $y_a$. What is the correct replacement for “symmetric function” in the super-setting? Do they arise somewhere naturally?